# Condition for no solution of system of linear inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

Suppose I have the following system of linear inequations $A x \le b$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, $b$ is an $n \times 1$ vector.

Are there some necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$, $b$, for which the above system has a solution? Any information on this would be helpful.

Comment: Some sufficient conditions:
If $A$ is invertible, there are always solutions.  
If $b \ge 0$, there are always solutions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Comment: @RobertIsrael Could you prove those two conditions as an answer?

Comment: In the two cases @RobertIsrael mentioned,, $x=A^{-1}b$ and $x=0$ are solutions.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks, I hadn't seeen the obvious.